# In Swift how to decode API keys that are Pascal Case?

Tags: json, swift, codable

I can easily decode the keys that are Camel Case:

```
struct TheData: Codable {
    let theNumber: Float
}
```

But I can not decode this version:

```
struct TheData: Codable {
    let TheNumber: Float
}
```

"TheNumber" is with first letter capitalized and Swift does allow constants starting with capital case. I have tried to lower case the first letter but it didn't work.

Comment: The API result is like this: TheNumber: 0.3420129716396332

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44396824/20287183

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decode a PascalCase JSON with JSONDecoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60746366/decode-a-pascalcase-json-with-jsondecoder)

Comment: Yes thanks. I found the answer in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44396500/how-do-i-use-custom-keys-with-swift-4s-decodable-protocol/44396824#44396824

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
struct TheData: Codable {
    let theNumber: Float
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case theNumber = "TheNumber"
    }
}
```

It is mentioned in: [How do I use custom keys with Swift 4's Decodable protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44396500/how-do-i-use-custom-keys-with-swift-4s-decodable-protocol/44396824#44396824)